# Updaters NSUserDefaults from alert action

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to setup a alert view that the user will type their salary into a text-field in the alert view, and then the NSUserdefault will update when the user clicks the done button. I'm getting an error when putting the code in the completion block.

```
var alertAction = UIAlertAction(
    title: "Done", 
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
    handler: { (action) -> Void in
        userDefaults.setValue(value: (altMessage.textFields![0] as! UITextField).text, forKey: "salary")
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message? Can be useful to investigate your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userDefaults.setValue(value:
```

No. That's not Swift. Delete that second `value:`, like this:

```
userDefaults.setValue(
```

Comment: yup thats was it... Thank You